# Is it possible to get rid of the badge reminder from VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The badge at the bottom right of "Accounts" button reminds me to sign in.

[image]

I don't want to sign in and I don't need it to remind me of that.

Is it possible to get rid of the badge reminder from VS code?

Comment: Try in `settings.json` to add either of the lines: `"git.countBadge": "off"` or `"gitlens.integrations.enabled": false` and restart VS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right-click the sidebar and Click accounts to remove it from view. This doesn't get rid of the reminder but it does remove the badge from view.

hope this helps